# jquery regex for numbers

Tags: jquery

I am trying to restrict my input field to numbers (they can be positive, negative and with a decimal point)

I did the following but this does not work as I want it

```
$(document).on('input', '[id^="original_invest"]', function(event) {
    var str = $(this).val();
    var patt = /\-?\d*\.?\d\d/g
    var result = str.match(patt);
    console.log(result);
});
```

First, it is always one char behind 
so if I type 5 and print result I see nothing and it is only matching after a certain amount of chars

So printing result for the following yields the following outputs
5 -> null
55 -> null
555 -> ["55"]
5555 -> ["555"]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `keyup` instead which should have applied your change to the value.  Or better yet, use `input`.  A left arrow would have a keyup, but not an input.  No need to evaluate for an arrow key.

Comment: changed to input
still getting null for the first value. For example, 1 -> null, 11 -> [11]

Comment: Can you update your code with what you are doing?  Cause nothing in your snipplet "outputs".  Though it should be said that the `\d\d` at the end of your regex is forcing it to match at least two digits.

Comment: but isn't d* says any number of digits with only 2 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The last two \d\d **force** there to be at least two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\.?\d\d` means "an optional `.` character followed by a digit followed by a digit". The last two digits are not optional so your regex will minimumly match 3 digits (as you can see 555 works).

You can use `^\-?\d+(\.\d+)?$` to match it instead.

**Regex Autopsy**:

- `^` - The string has to start with the next match:
- `\-?` - The literal character `-` matched 0 to 1 times
- `\d+` - A digit matched 1 to infinity times
- `(\.\d+)?`  - An optional regex group matching:

  - `\.` - A literal `.` character
  - `\d+` - A digit matched 1 to infinity times
- `$` - The string must end with the previous match (do remember that it's optional though)

[**Regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZMj8Wg/1)

[image]

[image]

**Note**:

As you can see `.33` is not considered a number. If you want this to work use `\d*` instead of `\d+` in the first digit in the regex. This means "matched 0 to infinity times" rather than "1 to infinity".

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You need to use the `keyup` event (as suggested in the comments above). `keypress` is the physical key being pushed, but the input value has not yet been updated. `keyup` is the physical key being released, and the input value has been updated.

Your regex needs some work:

- I would require at least one digit: `\d+`
- Since the decimal is optional, you should put that into it's own optional group: `(\.\d{1,2})?` - This allows a decimal followed by one or two digits. You can allow unlimited number of decimal digits by using `(\.\d+)?`
- You should put boundary markers(`^`, `$`) to signify the beginning and end of the input, and get rid of the global `/g` flag

Here's the final:

```
/^\-?\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```